# Problem with Displacement in material

Tags: mesh, materials, node-editor, displacement

I just added to my model some fast basics materials to see the preview result. However, it seems that Displacement node in material is curving one egde in strange way. It started to happen after some vertical subdivisions I added to the mesh. This effect is visible on the bottom edge on the render preview:
[image: displacement]

How can I get rid of this effect?

Comment: Displacement will displace the topology, if you only have several faces, it will move them, therefore what happens. What were you trying to do with this Displacement? It looks like you already have a Normal map to fake some bumps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displacement works by using **existing geometry on the object**.

It looks like your building has very little geometry, so only the small amount of existing vertices are moved causing this bending effect. To fix this, just select all of the edges in edit mode by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, and subdivide a few times to create more geometry. As a little note, displacement often works best when the faces on the object are mostly squares.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for answers. I guess I will see how big will be final scene and then decide if I should increase geometry, or just don't use displacement at all (just bumps).